# How to redirect port 80 to different server in nginx?

Tags: http, redirect, nginx, reverse-proxy

In my use case, I would like to redirect www.xyz.com/static to www.abc.com using nginx as reverse proxy. I have the following nginx configuration in place,

```
worker_processes  1;
events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}
http {
    include       mime.types;
    keepalive_timeout  65;
    client_max_body_size 500M;
    #timeouts
    proxy_connect_timeout       600;
    proxy_send_timeout          600;
    proxy_read_timeout          600;
    send_timeout                600;
    upstream s-content {
      server abc.com;
      keepalive 64;
    }
    #
    # The default server
    #
    server {
      listen   80;
      server_name  rproxy;
      location /static {
            rewrite /(.*) /$1 break;
            proxy_pass http://s-content;
            proxy_redirect off;
            proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            proxy_set_header   Host   $http_host;
            proxy_set_header   X-NginX-Proxy true;
            real_ip_header     X-Forwarded-For;
                real_ip_recursive  on;
            #proxy_set_header   Connection "";
            #proxy_http_version 1.1;
          }
        # redirect not found pages to the static page /404.html
        error_page  404  /404.html;
        location = /404.html {
            root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        }
        # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        }
    }
}
```

This server proxy is mapped to xyz.com and listens on port 80. I would like to redirect to abc.com when I get a request in abc.com/static. But for some reasons the rewrite is not working.

Could someone help me on this. I appreciate the help.

Comment: Are you attempting to proxy `xyz.com/static/foo` to `abc.com/foo` (because that is **not** what you have)?

Comment: @RichardSmith - oh ok. Then I am using a wrong regular expression in the rewrite. Is that right? Could you help me with the regular expression for routing xyz.com/static to abc.com ? Thanks

Comment: Try: `rewrite ^/static/?(.*)$ /$1 break;`

Comment: @RichardSmith - I updated but no luck :(. I get 404.

Comment: @RichardSmith - Do we need `$1` in the rewrite regex?

Comment: Look at the access logs for both `xyz.com` and `abc.com` to identify the cause of the `404` response.

Comment: @RichardSmith - I tried the /var/log/nginx/error.log. But it didn't help :(. Thank you for helping.

Comment: It will be in the access log not the error log.